# The way to use YARP from Matlab

Tags: java, matlab, swing, ros, yarp

I want to link YARP with Matlab to run [this system](https://github.com/robotology/wysiwyd/tree/master/main/src/modules/kinematicStructureLearning/matlabModuleKS). 
I set up based on [this](http://wiki.icub.org/wiki/Calling_yarp_from_Matlab).

First,

I download YARP from [github](https://github.com/robotology/yarp).

Next,

1. cmake example/swig
2. toggle CREATE_JAVA on
3. generate and compile the example SWIG project

I got the following compile error

```
Macro 'VOCAB' redefined                         Vocab.h
previous definition of 'VOCAB'                  yarp.i

Macro 'VOCAB4' redefined                        Vocab.h
previous definition of 'VOCAB4'                 yarp.i

Macro 'VOCAB3' redefined                        Vocab.h
previous definition of 'VOCAB3'                 yarp.i

Macro 'VOCAB2' redefined                        Vocab.h
previous definition of 'VOCAB2'                 yarp.i

Macro 'VOCAB1' redefined                        Vocab.h
previous definition of 'VOCAB1'                 yarp.i
```

My development environment

- windows10
- Matlab R2018a
- Yarp 2.3.72
- jdk 10.0.1

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if that wiki page is updated, this is the [official documentation](http://www.yarp.it/yarp_swig.html#yarp_swig_matlab) for using the java bindings on matlab.

Anyway, there are experimental [matlab bindings](https://github.com/robotology-playground/yarp-matlab-bindings) for using YARP in matlab without java, I recommend to try those.